# convirtiendo una tabla msql en json

Tags: mysql

estoy construyendo un json en PHP a través de una consulta de MySQL

**tabla Usuarios**
[image: tabla Usuarios]

**tabla id**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer la consulta

```
SELECT * 
FROM Usuarios 
INNER JOIN id 
WHERE Usuarios.ID_Usuario = id.id 
GROUP BY Usuarios.ID_Usuario
```

Me da este resultado,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi código en PHP

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios INNER JOIN id WHERE Usuarios.ID_Usuario = id.id ";
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");  

    if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query)) die();    
    $encabezado = array();    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){       
        $id = $row["ID_Usuario"];          
        $nombre = $row["Nombre_Usuario"];                  
        $usuario = $row["Usuario"];        
        $pass = $row["Pass"];          
        $empresa = $row["Empresa"];       
        $nit = $row["Nit"];
        $fechareg = $row["FECHA_REG"];
        $n1 = $row["Nota1"];
        $n2 = $row["Nota2"];
        $codigo = $row["id"];
        $producto = $row["nombre"];
        $valor = $row["valor"];
        $encabezado[] = array('id'=> $id,'nombre'=>$nombre,'usuario'=>$usuario,'clave'=>$pass,'empresa'=>$empresa,
        'nit'=>$nit,'fecha registro'=>$fechareg,'nota1'=>$n1,'nota2'=>$n2,'Productos' => ['codigo'=>$codigo,'producto'=>$producto,'valor'=>$valor]);       
    }    
    $json_datos = json_encode($encabezado,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    echo '<pre>'.$json_datos.'</pre>';
```

este es el resultado generado de mi codigo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero requiero que me salga asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco si alguien me puede dar una luz de que estoy haciendo mal o como puedo corregirlo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: La consulta no esta duplicando el ID,  es que literal la consulta te trae los datos que le estas solicitando.  Mas bien seria conveniente que nos expliques cual es el resultado que esperas o que es lo que quieres mostrar.

Comment: Tienes algunos detalles, la tabla `id` deberías renombrarla a `productos`; y sería mas conveniente que el elemento `Productos` del Json sea un arreglo: `"Productos" : [ {"codigo":"2", "producto": "camara", "valor": "452100.000"}, {"codigo":"2", "producto": "pc 2018 office", "valor": "15640000.000"} ]`. Tienes varias opciones, menciono tres: 1) Agrupando (un renglón) por usuario en SQL y separas los productos en PHP, 2) Siendo un renglón por producto en SQL, agrupas por usuario en PHP, 3) Dos consultas: una por usuario y otra por productos de cada usuario e ir armando poco a poco el json.

Comment: @sal realice los cambios como mencionas, para mi es mas facil realizarlo con el punto 3. pues no se como hacer la consulta donde me genere una sola linea por usuario,.

Comment: pero no se como organizar la impresion de json en PHP para que anide Productos dentro de usuarios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detecta el cambio de usuario, si es distinto al anterior agrega al arreglo el usuario anterior y crea un nuevo arreglo; siempre añade el producto al sub-arreglo `Productos`.

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios INNER JOIN id WHERE Usuarios.ID_Usuario = id.id ";
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion,'utf8');

    if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query)) die();
    $encabezado = array();
    $usuario = null;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        if( !isset($usuario) || $usuario['id'] !== $row['ID_Usuario'] ){
            if( isset($usuario) )
                $encabezado[] = $usuario;
            $usuario = array( 'id'     => $row['ID_Usuario']
                            , 'nombre' => $row['Nombre_Usuario']
                            , 'usuario'=> $row['Usuario']
                            , 'clave'  => $row['Pass']
                            , 'empresa'=> $row['Empresa']
                            , 'nit'    => $row['Nit']
                            , 'fecha registro' => $row['FECHA_REG']
                            , 'nota1'  => $row['Nota1']
                            , 'nota2'  => $row['Nota2']
                            , 'Productos' => array() 
                            );
        }
        $usuario['Productos'][] = array( 'codigo'   => $row['id']
                                       , 'producto' => $row['nombre']
                                       , 'valor'    => $row['valor']
                                       );
    }    
    $json_datos = json_encode($encabezado,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    echo '<pre>'.$json_datos.'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

La consulta te traerá todos los campos`(*)` de ambas tablas. En caso de que sea útil, te recomienda indicar los campos que deseas visualizar:

```
SELECT u.id, id.nombre FROM Usuarios as u INNER JOIN id as id WHERE Usuarios.ID_Usuario = id.id GROUP BY Usuarios.ID_Usuario
```

Solo te devolvería los campos, mientras que al indicar `*` te devolverá todos los campos de ambas tablas.